# Example of a vulnerability which is not a bug

Tags: security, wcf-security, code-access-security

I would like to ask if there is any simple example where a vulnerability is not a bug?

Comment: One analogy is where you **want** a back door in a concert for the VIPs to enter. You can post guards, but it doesn't beat having a brick wall where the door should be. A vulnerability that isn't seen as a bug is usually a feature.

Comment: Misconfiguration? You set the permission wrong on your database config file, and now all of the shared web host customers can see your database password. Not a bug because it works as designed.

Comment: Weak encryption key by design, e.g. DES with its 56-bit key.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy DES became weak as technology advanced, not "by design".

Comment: @Eugene: of course, it was not "designed to be weak". I meant "it was designed to use 56-bit encryption", which might be sufficient in the past, but today it presents a vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

Some protocols are implicitly designed simple and vulnerable as they are expected to be carried over secured channel. Eg. SFTP file transfer protocol has no authentication at all, because SFTP was expected to be used over SSH (though nothing technically prevents one from running SFTP over plain TCP).

Next you need to define what "bug" is. If we mean the bug to be the behavior which was designed/engineered differently than it appears to work, then anything which was vulnerable by design (for whatever reason) is not a bug.